# Does a programmer's "document template" with tags exist for Windows?

Tags: windows, language-agnostic, tags, auto-generate

I was wondering (*if possible*) if there was a program/tool/utility that when I create a new file and provide it with an extension that it creates the appropriate tags automatically?

For example, a new file I create called `index.php` would have the appropriate tags auto-generated inside:

```
<?php    
?>
```

I hope you get the idea.

Any information regarding this would be helpful.

Comment: Most HTML tags aren't required, so you don't really need it.

Comment: Yeah that is very true, I just tried to provide another example along with my PHP one. I removed the HTML segment part to avoid any debate about that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know about a portable utility, but on Windows, there's a built-in feature that does it.

From `regedit`, go to your `HKCR/.your-extension` (e.g. `HKCR/.php`). the `(Default)` value will contain the filetype class - go to either `HKCR/.your-extension/the-filetype-class` or `HKCR/the-filetype-class` (either will do), then inside create a key named `ShellNew`. In the key, create a string value called `FileName` and assign to it the file path of your template file.

Now all new files with this particular extension will be created containing the contents of your template.

Here's a [more detailed tutorial](http://mc-computing.com/WinExplorer/WinExplorerRegistry_ShellNew.htm).

Comment: Max, I am absolutely infatuated with you.

Comment: That's pretty cool. Does it work with just a few, select programs, or most of them will comply?

Comment: I even added "PHP script" to my New file menu, its amazing.

Answer (score 1):

If you run Linux with GNOME, maybe http://tombuntu.com/index.php/2008/02/13/add-your-document-templates-to-gnome/ is what you need.

There is probably something similar in other environments.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I was looking for something more Windows based. It was tough for me to look since I couldn't find a good enough term to describe what I wanted to achieve. The link was very helpful, thank you again.